# Parallelising an Exhaustive Search in Cython

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, cython, gil

I'm fairly new to Cython, and I'm trying to Cythonize some code of mine. I have a 3D array, `X`, of complex values (which I'm treating as a large 'stack' of square arrays) which has shape on the scale of `(small, small, huge)`, and I need to find the location and the absolute value of the largest above-diagonal item. I currently have an exhaustive search like this:

```
cdef double complex[:,:,:] Xcp = X.copy()

cdef Py_ssize_t h = Xcp.shape[0]
cdef Py_ssize_t w = Xcp.shape[1]
cdef Py_ssize_t l = Xcp.shape[2]
cdef Py_ssize_t j, k, m

cdef double tmptop = 0.0
cdef Py_ssize_t[:] coords = np.zeros((3), dtype="intp")
cdef double it

for j in range(l):
    for k in range(w):
        for m in range(k+1, h):
            it = cabs(Xcp[m, k, j])
            if it > tmptop:
                tmptop = it
                coords[0] = m
                coords[1] = k
                coords[2] = j
```

Note that I'm getting `cabs` from here:

```
cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double cabs(double complex)
```

This code is already quite a lot faster than what I had previously in Numpy, but I do feel as though it could be sped up, in particular paralellised.

I have tried changing the loop to this:

```
with nogil:
    for j in prange(l):
        for k in range(w):
            for m in range(k+1, h):
                it = abs(Xcp[m, k, j])
                if it > tmptop:
                    tmptop = it
                    coords[0] = m
                    coords[1] = k
                    coords[2] = j
```

Though I'm now getting the wrong result. What's going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduction of array in cython parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533455/reduction-of-array-in-cython-parallel)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101000/thread-local-arrays-in-cythons-prange-without-huge-memory-allocation) might also be relevant. The important thing to realise is that `coords` is shared between all the threads - I'm not convinced it's quite a duplicate because it isn't really a reduction

Comment: @ead I think my question is slightly different, though the approaches outlined there are still useful. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for the link. I see what the problem is now, and I think I will use a pointer to a preallocated array the size of the number of threads being used, and then do a linear search over that.