# Race Condition? - Multi-threaded results differ from single threaded

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython

I'm working on a parallel Cython algorithm that makes use of the "prange" function for parallelization. Basically, I have a numpy memory view that I update in parallel. I have noticed that there is a race condition or something going on as the values differ from the single threaded results. Does anyone have any direction to give me on where to look?

I have tried to adjust the "prange" arguments, but it does not seem to resolve the issue. My C understanding is fairly limited, but I did read it to see that the variables within the loop are all private as they should be.

The mp and mpi are the memory views.

```py
for diag in prange(minlag, profile_len, num_threads=n_jobs, nogil=True):
        c = 0
        for i in range(diag, diag + w):
            c = c + ((ts[i] - mu[diag]) * (ts[i-diag] - mu[0]))

        for offset in range(n - w - diag + 1):
            c = c + df[offset] * dg[offset + diag] + df[offset + diag] * dg[offset]
            c_cmp = c * sig[offset] * sig[offset + diag]

            # update the distance profile and profile index
            if c_cmp > mp[offset]:
                if c_cmp > 1:
                    c_cmp = 1
                mp[offset] = c_cmp
                mpi[offset] = offset + diag

            if c_cmp > mp[offset + diag]:
                if c_cmp > 1:
                    c_cmp = 1
                mp[offset + diag] = c_cmp
                mpi[offset + diag] = offset
```

mp and mpi values should be the same for both single and multi-threaded. Right now that is not the case.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @ead I mostly agree with you: for debugging questions (which this is) it's always an improvement to produce an [mre] (and so it is helpful for you to point it out). If I can quickly see the answer without it then I think it's necessary to insist on it (but I certainly don't object to it being closed if enough people come along before me and decide they can't reproduce the problem). What I probably should have done was just answer the question and not comment on it, since the comment looked like it was criticising and it really wasn't supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
for offset in range(n - w - diag + 1):
      # ... some stuff ...
            mp[offset] = c_cmp
            mpi[offset] = offset + diag
      # ... some stuff ...
            mp[offset + diag] = c_cmp
            mpi[offset + diag] = offset
```

The assignments to `mp` and `mpi` get run for a range of offsets from `0` to some number (which we don't know because it's an incomplete example, but which doesn't particularly matter). This happens *in every thread*.

Since your algorithm seems to work by both updated `mp` in the loop and using `mp` in the same loop it doesn't seem particularly parallelizable to me. (It might be possible to parallelize the inner (`offset`) loop instead, but I think that would cause issues with the `...[offset + diag]` lines.)

---

Essentially, if you parallelize the loop with index `diag` then the only things you should change in the loop are:

1. Single values as a "reduction variable" (`+-*/`)
2. Arrays indexed with `diag` **and only `diag`**.

Other things are sometimes possible but you **must** understand what you're doing fully and have proved to yourself that multiple threads are not writing the same data.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I was under the same impression as you and just wanted clarification to ease my stubborn mind. I think another approach would be to duplicate (mp and mpi) for each thread and combine the results at the end right?

Comment: Yes - that would probably work. You want to make `mp` and `mpi` a 2D array with the second dimension being the number of threads. I know I've written answers suggesting a similar approach... I'll see if I can find one

Comment: Second part of [answer A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101000/thread-local-arrays-in-cythons-prange-without-huge-memory-allocation/52131123#52131123) or maybe [answer B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533455/reduction-of-array-in-cython-parallel/36534428#36534428). I prefer the code in answer A.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to resolve with the 2D array approach per your first answer.